# How does super()._init_ work in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I would just like a general explanation of how to use a class and subclass in pygame?

Comment: keep snake as list of its segments/elements - every element keep its position - first element is snake head. When snake moves then you append new position of head at the beginning of list and you remove last element - and snake/list have the same length. When snake eats something then once you don't remove last element from list. This way snake is longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep snake as list of its segments/elements. Every element keeps segment position `(x,y)`. First element is snake head. ie.

```
snake = [(10,10), (11,10), (12,10)]
```

When snake moves then you append new position of head at the beginning of list and you remove last element - and snake/list have the same length.

```
# new head position
snake.insert(0, (9,10))

# remove tail     
snake.pop()
```

When snake eats something then you don't remove last element from list. This way snake is longer.

```
# init data
make_longer = False

...

# snake eat sothing
make_longer = True

...

# new head position
snake.insert(0, (9,10))

# remove tail     
if make_longer:
    # skip removing last element once 
    make_longer = False
else:
    snake.pop()
```

If you want to make longer more than one element then don't remove last element more than once.

```
# init data
make_longer = 0

...

# snake eat sothing
# make_longer = 3
make_longer += 3 # better when snake eats more apples in short time

...

# new head position
snake.insert(0, (9,10))

# remove tail     
if make_longer > 0:
    make_longer -= 1
else:
    snake.pop()
```